# Dropbox API - File read & upload node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dropbox-api

I am using the dropbox API to read a file from the node.js file structure and then uploading that file into a dropbox folder.

The file gets uploaded but its **empty** the size of the uploaded file is **0 bytes**

```
var path = require("path");
var temp_dir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'pdf/');

 if (!fs.existsSync(temp_dir))
    fs.mkdirSync(temp_dir);
    fs.readFile(temp_dir + 'report.pdf', function read(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

    fileupload(data);
  });
```

**File upload Code:**

```
function fileupload(name, content) {
     request.put('https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/my_reports/report.pdf', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'TOKEN HERE',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
                },
                body: content
            }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, bodymsg) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("File uploaded to dropbox successfully!");
                    fs.unlink(temp_dir + 'report.pdf', function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        else {
                            console.log("file deleted from server!");
                        }
                    })
                    request.post('https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/shares/auto/MY_reports/report.pdf' + '?short_url=false', {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: 'TOKEN HERE'
                        }
                    }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, bodymsg) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('Shared link 2 ' + JSON.parse(httpResponse.body).url);

                        }
                    });

                }
            });
         }
```

**The uploaded file in dropbox:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fileupload` takes two parameters: `name` and `content`, but you're only passing one parameter. This means `content` is `undefined`, which is why you're uploading an empty file.

Since you're not actually using `name`, just remove that parameter from the definition of `fileupload`:

```
function fileupload(content) {
  ...
```

**PLEASE NOTE**

You're using Dropbox API v1, which was deprecated over a year ago and is [due to be turned off soon](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/06/updated-api-v1-deprecation-timeline/). You should switch to [API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly upload your file using my tiny dropbox v2 api wrapper ([dropbox-v2-api](https://github.com/adasq/dropbox-v2-api)):

```
const dropboxUploadStream = dropbox({
    resource: 'files/upload',
    parameters: {
        path: '/MY_reports/report.pdf'
    }
}, (err, result) => {
    //upload completed 
});

fs.createReadStream(temp_dir + 'report.pdf').pipe(dropboxUploadStream);
```

Comment: Hi, Im trying to use your library but I can seem to make it work. When I `console.log(result)` I get `undefined` and the file does not upload. Can you help?

Comment: @Skywalker Please make sure:

1. you have authenticated before, or
2. the stream is valid

Comment: Hi. It’s is authenticated. And how do I check whether the stream is valid. I copy pasted the code from the examples on your github page.

Comment: How about another API calls. Do they work properly? Please, check this one: https://github.com/adasq/dropbox-v2-api/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#usersget_current_account-see-docs.